# Operand for matching any one of multiple cases

Tags: python-3.x, matching, operands

I would like to have an if statement where the match is one of several numbers without using a large number of `|` bars because I have many matching cases

```
if number == 1 | number == 5 | number == 7
  do stuff
```

In R, there is the operand %in% that works sort of like the following:

```
if number %in% [1,5,7]
  do stuff
```

Is there a similar operand/ability in python?

Thanks

Comment: You can do literally `if number in [1,5,7]:`. Python's pretty expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```py
if number in [1, 5, 7]:
```